# не могу переписать код

Tags: javascript, рекурсия, for

У меня такой код:

```
function fold(array, operation, initial) {
    if (arguments.length === 3) {
        array.push(initial);
    }
    return array.length == 1 
    ? array[0] : operation(array[0], fold(array.splice(1), operation));
}
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
function mul(a, b) {
    return a * b;
}    
console.log(fold([1,2,3],add,10));//16
console.log(fold([1,2,3],mul,10));//60
```

Нужно переписать через простой `for`.
Я делаю так :

```
function fold(array, operation, initial) {
    if (array.length === 1) return array[0];
    if (arguments.length === 3) array.push(initial);
    let res = array[0];

    for(let i = 1;i < array.length; i++){
        res += operation(res, array[i]);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: покажите вашу попытку решить, а мы подскажем что не так и как это исправить, сейчас это похоже на учебное задание

Comment: добавьте это в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы зря добавили `+=`, `res` уже передается в функцию, не нужно аккумулировать в таком случает результат

```js
function alterFold(array, operation, initial) {
  if (array.length === 1) return array[0];
  if (arguments.length === 3) array.unshift(initial);
  let res = array.pop();
  while(array.length){
    res = operation(res, array.pop());
  }
  return res;
}


function fold(array, operation, initial) {
    if (arguments.length === 3) {
      array.push(initial);
    }
    return array.length == 1 ? array[0] : operation(array[0], fold(array.splice(1), operation));
}
              
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
              
function mul(a, b) {
   return a * b;
}    

console.log('original fold');
console.log(fold([1,2,3],add,10));
console.log(fold([1,2,3],mul,10));
console.log('alter fold');
console.log(alterFold([1,2,3],add,10));
console.log(alterFold([1,2,3],mul,10));
console.log('Grundy`s suggestion');
console.log(fold([1,2,3], (a,b)=>a/b,10)) 
console.log(alterFold([1,2,3], (a,b)=>a/b,10))
```

Comment: спасибо, я просто дурак не увидил).

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, не там разница с какой стороны сворачивается: ((1+2)+3) - это с начала массива: (1 + (2 + 3)) с конца

Comment: добавь пример `fold([1,2,3], (a,b)=>a/b,1)` и `alterFold([1,2,3], (a,b)=>a/b,1)` :)

Comment: @Grundy добавил-пофиксил =)